# Using javascript to calculate the total cost of an order based on quantity of products in html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Trying to use javascript to calculate the total cost of an order using the quantity inputted through the form in html but the total is not displaying in the input box. Been messing around with it for a few days and yesterday was showing NaN but now the box stays completely blank. It's all within a singlular webpage as a pratical assessment for school and am just using the script tag.

See the js below

```
function calculatePrice()
            {
            //select data  
            var cappuccino = 3.00;
            var espresso = 2.25;
            var latte = 2.50;
            var iced = 2.50;

            var quantityCappuccino = document.getElementByID("quantityCappuccino").value;
            var quantityEspresso = document.getElementByID("quantityEspresso").value;
            var quantityLatte = document.getElementByID("quantityLatte").value;
            var quantityIced = document.getElementByID("quantityIced").value;

            //calculate final cost  
            var total = (quantityCappuccino * cappuccino) + (quantityEspresso * espresso) + (quantityLatte * latte) + (quantityIced * iced); 

            //print value to orderTotal 
            document.getElementById("orderTotal").value=total;
        }
```

And here is the html for the form

```
 <table>
                    <tr align="center"> 
                        <td><hr>
                            Hot Drinks<hr>                  
                        </td>
                        <td><hr>
                            Price<hr>
                        </td>
                        <td><hr>
                            Quantity<hr>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <form name="calcuccino">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Cappuccino  
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            $3.00
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <input type="number" id="quantityCappucino" name="quantityCappuccino" value="0">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Espresso
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            $2.25
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <input type="number" id="quantityEspresso" name="quantityEspresso" value="0">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                                Latte
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            $2.50
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <input type="number" id="quantityLatte" name="quantityLatte" value="0">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Iced
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            $2.50
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <input type="number" id="quantityIced" name="quantityIced" value="0">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <hr>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="takeaway" name="takeaway">Takeaway?</option>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br>
                            <button type="button" onclick="calculatePrice()">Submit Order</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <br>
                            <hr>
                            Order total: <b>$</b>
                            <input type="text"  name="orderTotal" id="orderTotal" Size=6 readonly>
```

Comment: I wouldn't hurt it reduce the question size, perhaps a single item and see if that sums. In minimizing the problem you will have less to look at. Also you are fetching Strings... so using parseInt or parseFloat, Number() or such is certainly going to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two errors:

(1) In your second four `var` statements, it's `getElementById` not `getElementByID` (don't all-cap "Id").

(2) Your first `<input>` tag has the id name misspelled.  It should be `quantityCappuccino` (identical to the `name` attribute).

After fixing those, the code worked like a charm.

NOTE: It took me seconds to figure this out because the error console (In FireFox, strike the F12 key to open it) reported the problems.  That console is your friend.

Comment: bless so much saved a life today <3

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```js
$("#orderTotal").click(function () {
    calculatePrice();
});

function calculatePrice()
{
    //select data
    var cappuccino = 3.00;
    var espresso = 2.25;
    var latte = 2.50;
    var iced = 2.50;

    var quantityCappuccino = $("#quantityCappucino").val();
    var quantityEspresso =  $("#quantityEspresso").val();
    var quantityLatte =  $("#quantityLatte").val();
    var quantityIced = $("#quantityIced").val();

    //calculate final cost
    var total = (quantityCappuccino * cappuccino) + (quantityEspresso * espresso) + (quantityLatte * latte) + (quantityIced * iced);

    console.log(total);
    //print value to orderTotal
    $("#orderTotal").val(total);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body>
<table>
    <tr align="center">
        <td><hr>
            Hot Drinks<hr>
        </td>
        <td><hr>
            Price<hr>
        </td>
        <td><hr>
            Quantity<hr>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <form name="calcuccino">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Cappuccino
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                $3.00
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="number" id="quantityCappucino" name="quantityCappuccino" value="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Espresso
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                $2.25
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="number" id="quantityEspresso" name="quantityEspresso" value="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Latte
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                $2.50
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="number" id="quantityLatte" name="quantityLatte" value="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Iced
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                $2.50
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="number" id="quantityIced" name="quantityIced" value="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <hr>
                <input type="checkbox" id="takeaway" name="takeaway">Takeaway?</option>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <br>
                <button type="button" onclick="calculatePrice()">Submit Order</button>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
                <hr>
                Order total: <b>$</b>
                <input type="text"  name="orderTotal" id="orderTotal" Size=6 readonly>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```